# Split large XML file after string found

Tags: c#, xml, string

What I have:

A large XML file @ nearly 1 million lines worth of content. Example of content:

```
<etc35yh3 etc="numbers" etc234="a" etc345="date"><something><some more something></some more something></something></etc123>
<etc123 etc="numbers" etc234="a" etc345="date"><something><some more something></some more something></something></etc123>
<etc15y etc="numbers" etc234="a" etc345="date"><something><some more something></some more something></something></etc123>
```

^ repeat that by 900k or so lines (content changing of course)

What I need:

Search the XML file for `"<etc123"`. Once found move (write) that line along with all lines below it to a separate XML file.

Would it be advisable to use a method such as File.ReadAllLines for the search portion? What would you all recommend for the writing portion. Line by line is not an option as far as I can tell as it would take much too long.

Comment: `effectively discarding the content above it.` what does this mean

Comment: Should the resulting file be valid XML?

Comment: @Anirudha like disregarding it - aka, not write it (ignore it)

Comment: @Austin Salonen,
right now they are opening the file within notepad++ and editing it by hand and then re-saving as another XML file. I will say probably not.

Comment: If result does not need to be XML - just use ReadToEnd + IndexOf and write the tail of the string to new file... Also I strongly doubt you want that... If output needs to be XML - please use XML APIs to read and write.

Comment: do you need to keep original file ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @John - thank you, old habits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quite literaly discard the content above your search string, I would not use File.ReadAllLines, as it would load the entire file into memory.  Try File.Open and wrap it in a StreamReader.  Loop on StreamReader.ReadLine, then start writing to a new StreamWriter, or do a byte copy on the underlying filestream.

An example of how to do so with StreamWriter/StreamReader alone is listed below.

```
//load the input file
//open with read and sharing
using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream("input.txt", 
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) 
{
    //use streamreader to search for start
    var srInput = new StreamReader(fsInput);
    string searchString = "two";
    string cSearch = null;
    bool found = false;
    while ((cSearch = srInput.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (cSearch.StartsWith(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
        throw new Exception("Searched string not found.");

    //we have the data, write to a new file
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(
        new FileStream("out.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, //create or overwrite
            FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))) // write only, no sharing
    {
        //write the line that we found in the search
        sw.WriteLine(cSearch);

        string cline = null;
        while ((cline = srInput.ReadLine()) != null)
            sw.WriteLine(cline);
    }
}

//both files are closed and complete
```

Comment: +1 as it answers the question with good comments... BTW, byte copy will be hard as one does not know encoding... And StreamReader will not be able to handle non-UTF8/16 encodings if specified in XML... (doubt if anyone cares so).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I agree Re: byte copy, I had hoped that there was a way to seek with StreamReader, but neglected to consider the buffering going on.  Unless the document were very large, or there were a signifcant performance requriement, I would probably stay with StreamReader.

Comment: Success. With only a minor change (added an ending parentheses to the "if (cSerach.StartsWith" line). I believe this should do it - appreciate the assistance everyone

Answer (score 3):

You can copy with LINQ2XML

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourXML.xml");
XDocument newDoc=new XDocument();

foreach(XElement elm in doc.DescendantsAndSelf("etc123"))
{
newDoc.Add(elm);
}

newDoc.Save("yourOutputXML.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do one line at a time...  Would not use read to end if checking contents of each line.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("MyHugeXML.xml");
FileInfo outFile = new FileInfo("ResultFile.xml");

using(FileStream write = outFile.Create())
using(StreamReader sr = file.OpenRead())
{
    bool foundit = false;
    string line;
    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if(foundit)
        {
            write.WriteLine(line);
        }
        else if (line.Contains("<etc123"))
        {
            foundit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, this method may not produce valid XML, given your requirements.